# First element of an array with condition

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a shorter way to find the first element in an array meeting some conditions than this:

```
my_array[ my_array.index {|x| x.some_test} ]
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_array.find{|x| x.some_test }
```

Or here's a shortcut (thanks @LarsHaugseth for reminding about it)

```
my_array.find(&:some_test)
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `my_array.find(&:some_test)`

Answer (score 5):

As for me find sounds confusing. As i am expecting receive more than one object for such a request.

I prefer to use `detect` for getting distinct one.

And `select` for finding all of them.

Here what ruby docs tells about them:

```
detect(ifnone = nil) {|obj| block } → obj or nil click to toggle source 
find(ifnone = nil) {|obj| block } → obj or nil 
detect(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator 
find(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator
```

Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

```
find_all {|obj| block } → array click to toggle source
select {|obj| block } → array
find_all → an_enumerator
select → an_enumerator
```

Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which block is not false

Comment: find/detect, map/collect, reduce/inject - there's a method for everyone :)

Comment: To me, `detect` doesn't sound like a right method at all. `find` at least can *find* and return something. What `detect` does and returns - I have no idea without consulting the docs.

Comment: Still, the ruby community has mostly settled on `find`. A good reason for you to switch.

Comment: `detect` is useful when you're dealing with active record objects and such (where `find` is overridden and does a DB query instead)